# Can you ignore items using fuzzySearch plugin for list.js?

Tags: jquery-ui, fuzzy-search, items, listjs

I'm following the instructions here http://www.listjs.com/docs/plugins/fuzzysearch and have managed to get it working.

My issue is the following: I have two sortable columns. I want the search to only effect the left column and ignore the items on the right column.

Example: On initial load, all items are on the left column. I drag an item to the right column. Now if I use the fuzzySearch, it includes the items on right column and spits it back into the left column.

Side note: I'm just using JQuery UI for the sortable portion of it.